# How to use the "buildfire run" command?

Tags: windows, bash, ubuntu, buildfire

When I try and use the command "buildfire run" while inside BuildFireSDK I get an error:

buildfire run

```
Server running on [::]:3030
error { Error: Command failed: open http://localhost:3030/pluginTester/index.html
open: ioctl(VT_GETSTATE): Inappropriate ioctl for device

 at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:275:12)
 at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
 at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
 at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
 at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:346:11)
 at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
 at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
 at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:567:12)
killed: false,
code: 4,
signal: null,
cmd: 'open http://localhost:3030/pluginTester/index.html' }
stdout
stderr open: ioctl(VT_GETSTATE): Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

I am not sure what the error inappropriate ioctl even means. I also checked to see if /pluginTester/index.html was there and it was, so it should be a simple matter of the bash just running the code in my browser.

EDIT: Looks like I can still access buildfire by manually visiting localhost:3030. Not sure if this error will cause problems in the future, however.

Comment: Hey David, which operating system are you running? Also, this could be an innocuous error for something like trying to update your terminals colors. I mention this because the server seems to be running if you navigate to it manually.

Comment: I am running Windows 10, some comments I found online about ioctl says it could be a permissions problem, but running in sudo or in the root doesn't fix the problem. After I found out that the server still runs, its really not even a problem because it takes like 3 seconds to open chrome to localhost3030 anyway.